# Wrong output when printing long double with printf in mingw

Tags: c, mingw, long-double

I was trying to use long doubles in a bigger code but even this doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    
    long double I = 10.0;
    long double YOU = 2.0;
    long double WE = I/YOU;
    printf("%Lf", I);


    return 0;
}
```

No errors, but the output is

```
-0.000000
```

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue in `linux-gcc 11.1.0`. The output is 10.000000 on my side.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version of it? On what system?

Comment: I installed minGW installation manager

Comment: if that's the answer..?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code itself (except that you print the wrong value).

Comment: MinGW uses the Microsoft runtime, and there is said to be some problem. What happens if you try to replace `printf()` by `__mingw_printf()`?

Comment: MS doesn't support `long double` but implements it as `double`.

Comment: Might need `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` as the very first line.

Comment: which compiler do you recommend me so I solve the issue definitely?

Comment: do you know perhaps if there is also a 'scanf()' with the same prefix __mingw_ ? @thebusybee

Comment: Are you sure you actually *need* the extra range and precision of `long double`? Typically, you should use `double` unless there is a good reason not to, because that is the default type for literal floating point values and for arguments to variadic functions.

Comment: yes, I am doing a math project @WeatherVane

Comment: I think the MinGW-w64 compilers installed by MSYS2 default to using their own formatted I/O functions (for `printf` etc.) in place of the ones from MSVCRT.DLL.